# Check if a certain record is in the file

Tags: java, junit, io, bufferedreader, filereader

I am a newbie. I am working on a JUnit test. Here is what I am testing: I have an input file with list of records. If a record has an email, I have to add it to my output file, called myemailfile.txt

In my JUnit test I have to test whether the person with email=testEmail@gmail.com is included in myemailfile.txt

Can somebody please advise on how to go through the file and check whether such record made it to the file.

```
Here is my file:

    First Name,Last Name,Email,Id
    John       ,Dough       ,johnsemail@gmail.com                        ,12345
    Jane       ,Smith       ,mytestemail@gmail.com                        ,86547
    Mary       ,Wells       ,johnsemail@gmail.com                        ,76543
```

and below is my test

```
@Test
public void isRecordIncludedInEmailFile() throws IOException{       

    String testFile = "C:/Users/myname/myemailfile.txt";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String fileSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] field = line.split(fileSplitBy);

  //read through the file and see if the email that I expect (testEmail@gmail.com) exists in the file
  System.out.println("Email [email= " + field[2] + " , first name=" + field[0] + "]");

  //the line below should assert if "testEmail@gmail.com" exists in the file             
     // assertEquals("testEmail@gmail.com", field[2]);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You seem to miss the crucial point of unit tests: you use them to *test* your java classes; not that some file contains some content.

In other words, the reasonable thing to do here:

1. Create a **class** that represents such a record, maybe called *PersonInformation*
2. Write code that reads such a file, and turns the file content into some array or List of *PersonInformation* objects
3. Then you write a unit test that creates a faked file with some data; you run your code ... and test that the expected *PersonInformation* objects were found, read in and stored in that list.

And final hint: unless this is a "study exercise", you do **not** want to parse that file content manually. You see, that data is using the CSV format (comma separated values). Writing code to read such data and parse it ... means re-inventing the wheel. There are a lot of libraries out there that do that work for you.